# Angular Material styles not applied

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm running node 12.18.2
I installed the latest version of Angular CLI (10.0.2)

I created a new app (ng new APP_NAME);
I installed angular material (ng add @angular/material)

Then I try to display some buttons an this is what i get:

[image]

This is my configuration:

package.json:

```
    {
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "~10.0.3",
      "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
      "@angular/common": "~10.0.3",
      "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.3",
      "@angular/core": "~10.0.3",
      "@angular/forms": "~10.0.3",
      "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.3",
      "@angular/router": "~10.0.3",
      "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
      "tslib": "^2.0.0",
      "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
      },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.2", 
      "@angular/cli": "~10.0.2",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.3",
      "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
      "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
      "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
      "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
      "karma": "~5.0.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
      "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
      "protractor": "~7.0.0",
      "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
      "tslint": "~6.1.0",
      "typescript": "~3.9.5"
     }
```

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
             "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
             "src/styles.scss"
           ],
```

i added this in the styles.scss file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

I'm expecting the buttons to look like this:
[image]
What am I missing?

Comment: Please check your DevTool if any material css is successfully loaded. Also what happens if you place the css include in your index.html like: <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-565o22) with the working styles. Maybe you have to add the `MatDividerModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule` to your module.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatDividerModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```